# find the difference use javascript

Tags: javascript, hashtable

this is a leetcode question.

Given two strings s and t which consist of only lowercase letters.

String t is generated by random shuffling string s and then add one more letter at a random position.

Find the letter that was added in t.

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-difference/
I'm trying to think a hash table way but seems I m wrong.

```
var findTheDifference = function(s, t) {
var hashTable = {};
var array = s.split('');
   array.forEach(function (element) {
   hashTable[element] = element;
   });
   for( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
      if(!hashTable.hasOwnProperty(t.charAt(i))) {
         return t.charAt(i);
      }
  }
};
```

this wrong code can pass the sample Input:

```
Input:
s = "abcd"
t = "abcde"

Output:
e
```

but for large strings will be wrong

```
Input :"ymbgaraibkfmvocpizdydugvalagaivdbfsfbepeyccqfepzvtpyxtbadkhmwmoswrcxnargtlswqemafandgkmydtimuzvjwxvlfwlhvkrgcsithaqlcvrihrwqkpjdhgfgreqoxzfvhjzojhghfwbvpfzectwwhexthbsndovxejsntmjihchaotbgcysfdaojkjldprwyrnischrgmtvjcorypvopfmegizfkvudubnejzfqffvgdoxohuinkyygbdzmshvyqyhsozwvlhevfepdvafgkqpkmcsikfyxczcovrmwqxxbnhfzcjjcpgzjjfateajnnvlbwhyppdleahgaypxidkpwmfqwqyofwdqgxhjaxvyrzupfwesmxbjszolgwqvfiozofncbohduqgiswuiyddmwlwubetyaummenkdfptjczxemryuotrrymrfdxtrebpbjtpnuhsbnovhectpjhfhahbqrfbyxggobsweefcwxpqsspyssrmdhuelkkvyjxswjwofngpwfxvknkjviiavorwyfzlnktmfwxkvwkrwdcxjfzikdyswsuxegmhtnxjraqrdchaauazfhtklxsksbhwgjphgbasfnlwqwukprgvihntsyymdrfovaszjywuqygpvjtvlsvvqbvzsmgweiayhlubnbsitvfxawhfmfiatxvqrcwjshvovxknnxnyyfexqycrlyksderlqarqhkxyaqwlwoqcribumrqjtelhwdvaiysgjlvksrfvjlcaiwrirtkkxbwgicyhvakxgdjwnwmubkiazdjkfmotglclqndqjxethoutvjchjbkoasnnfbgrnycucfpeovruguzumgmgddqwjgdvaujhyqsqtoexmnfuluaqbxoofvotvfoiexbnprrxptchmlctzgqtkivsilwgwgvpidpvasurraqfkcmxhdapjrlrnkbklwkrvoaziznlpor"


"qhxepbshlrhoecdaodgpousbzfcqjxulatciapuftffahhlmxbufgjuxstfjvljybfxnenlacmjqoymvamphpxnolwijwcecgwbcjhgdybfffwoygikvoecdggplfohemfypxfsvdrseyhmvkoovxhdvoavsqqbrsqrkqhbtmgwaurgisloqjixfwfvwtszcxwktkwesaxsmhsvlitegrlzkvfqoiiwxbzskzoewbkxtphapavbyvhzvgrrfriddnsrftfowhdanvhjvurhljmpxvpddxmzfgwwpkjrfgqptrmumoemhfpojnxzwlrxkcafvbhlwrapubhveattfifsmiounhqusvhywnxhwrgamgnesxmzliyzisqrwvkiyderyotxhwspqrrkeczjysfujvovsfcfouykcqyjoobfdgnlswfzjmyucaxuaslzwfnetekymrwbvponiaojdqnbmboldvvitamntwnyaeppjaohwkrisrlrgwcjqqgxeqerjrbapfzurcwxhcwzugcgnirkkrxdthtbmdqgvqxilllrsbwjhwqszrjtzyetwubdrlyakzxcveufvhqugyawvkivwonvmrgnchkzdysngqdibhkyboyftxcvvjoggecjsajbuqkjjxfvynrjsnvtfvgpgveycxidhhfauvjovmnbqgoxsafknluyimkczykwdgvqwlvvgdmufxdypwnajkncoynqticfetcdafvtqszuwfmrdggifokwmkgzuxnhncmnsstffqpqbplypapctctfhqpihavligbrutxmmygiyaklqtakdidvnvrjfteazeqmbgklrgrorudayokxptswwkcircwuhcavhdparjfkjypkyxhbgwxbkvpvrtzjaetahmxevmkhdfyidhrdeejapfbafwmdqjqszwnwzgclitdhlnkaiyldwkwwzvhyorgbysyjbxsspnjdewjxbhpsvj"
```

Thanks for any suggestion~~~~

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more a question for the cold golf exchange.

Comment: You're only storing the *existence* (or lack therefo) of a letter. But to deal with the sample input, you need to store the *count* of how many times that letter appears in each string, and look for variation between those counts.

Comment: oh, I see, Thank you T.J.

Comment: @Robusto This is my first question on StackOverflow. Could you please tell me why this is off-topic? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to sort the strings, then find where the first difference between them is:

```
var str = "1122334477422";
var str2 = "15122332247744";
var sorted = str.split('').sort();
var sorted2 = str2.split('').sort()
for(var i = 0; i< sorted2.length; i++){
    if(i == sorted2.length || sorted[i] != sorted2[i]){
        alert(sorted2[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table for counting. Add for every letter in the original string one and subtract one for every letter in the manipulated string. Then take only the hashes with nonempty count.

```js
var data1 = "ymbgaraibkfmvocpizdydugvalagaivdbfsfbepeyccqfepzvtpyxtbadkhmwmoswrcxnargtlswqemafandgkmydtimuzvjwxvlfwlhvkrgcsithaqlcvrihrwqkpjdhgfgreqoxzfvhjzojhghfwbvpfzectwwhexthbsndovxejsntmjihchaotbgcysfdaojkjldprwyrnischrgmtvjcorypvopfmegizfkvudubnejzfqffvgdoxohuinkyygbdzmshvyqyhsozwvlhevfepdvafgkqpkmcsikfyxczcovrmwqxxbnhfzcjjcpgzjjfateajnnvlbwhyppdleahgaypxidkpwmfqwqyofwdqgxhjaxvyrzupfwesmxbjszolgwqvfiozofncbohduqgiswuiyddmwlwubetyaummenkdfptjczxemryuotrrymrfdxtrebpbjtpnuhsbnovhectpjhfhahbqrfbyxggobsweefcwxpqsspyssrmdhuelkkvyjxswjwofngpwfxvknkjviiavorwyfzlnktmfwxkvwkrwdcxjfzikdyswsuxegmhtnxjraqrdchaauazfhtklxsksbhwgjphgbasfnlwqwukprgvihntsyymdrfovaszjywuqygpvjtvlsvvqbvzsmgweiayhlubnbsitvfxawhfmfiatxvqrcwjshvovxknnxnyyfexqycrlyksderlqarqhkxyaqwlwoqcribumrqjtelhwdvaiysgjlvksrfvjlcaiwrirtkkxbwgicyhvakxgdjwnwmubkiazdjkfmotglclqndqjxethoutvjchjbkoasnnfbgrnycucfpeovruguzumgmgddqwjgdvaujhyqsqtoexmnfuluaqbxoofvotvfoiexbnprrxptchmlctzgqtkivsilwgwgvpidpvasurraqfkcmxhdapjrlrnkbklwkrvoaziznlpor",
    data2 = "qhxepbshlrhoecdaodgpousbzfcqjxulatciapuftffahhlmxbufgjuxstfjvljybfxnenlacmjqoymvamphpxnolwijwcecgwbcjhgdybfffwoygikvoecdggplfohemfypxfsvdrseyhmvkoovxhdvoavsqqbrsqrkqhbtmgwaurgisloqjixfwfvwtszcxwktkwesaxsmhsvlitegrlzkvfqoiiwxbzskzoewbkxtphapavbyvhzvgrrfriddnsrftfowhdanvhjvurhljmpxvpddxmzfgwwpkjrfgqptrmumoemhfpojnxzwlrxkcafvbhlwrapubhveattfifsmiounhqusvhywnxhwrgamgnesxmzliyzisqrwvkiyderyotxhwspqrrkeczjysfujvovsfcfouykcqyjoobfdgnlswfzjmyucaxuaslzwfnetekymrwbvponiaojdqnbmboldvvitamntwnyaeppjaohwkrisrlrgwcjqqgxeqerjrbapfzurcwxhcwzugcgnirkkrxdthtbmdqgvqxilllrsbwjhwqszrjtzyetwubdrlyakzxcveufvhqugyawvkivwonvmrgnchkzdysngqdibhkyboyftxcvvjoggecjsajbuqkjjxfvynrjsnvtfvgpgveycxidhhfauvjovmnbqgoxsafknluyimkczykwdgvqwlvvgdmufxdypwnajkncoynqticfetcdafvtqszuwfmrdggifokwmkgzuxnhncmnsstffqpqbplypapctctfhqpihavligbrutxmmygiyaklqtakdidvnvrjfteazeqmbgklrgrorudayokxptswwkcircwuhcavhdparjfkjypkyxhbgwxbkvpvrtzjaetahmxevmkhdfyidhrdeejapfbafwmdqjqszwnwzgclitdhlnkaiyldwkwwzvhyorgbysyjbxsspnjdewjxbhpsvj",
    hash = Object.create(null),
    count = function (a) { hash[a] = (hash[a] || 0) + this; },
    result;

data1.split('').forEach(count, 1);
data2.split('').forEach(count, -1);

result = Object.keys(hash).filter(function (k) { return hash[k]; });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, I should think about counting. thanks